# Loop through inventory not running what its told?

Tags: java, minecraft

```
ItemStack item = PvP.inv.getItem(0);
SkullMeta meta = (SkullMeta)item.getItemMeta();
ItemStack item1 = PvP.inv.getItem(1);
ItemStack item2 = PvP.inv.getItem(2);
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if(sender instanceof Player) {
    Player p = (Player)sender;
    String name = p.getName();

    if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("pvpexit")) {
                if(item != null) {
                    if(item.hasItemMeta()) {
                        if(item.getItemMeta().hasDisplayName()) {
                                PvP.inv.setItem(0, null);
                                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "meng");
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    return false;
}
```

I'm guessing there's something I'm missing out which is very simple, but right now I'm just not seeing it, so what's the problem? Nothing happens when I run the command.

Comment: `ItemStack item = PvP.inv.getItem(0);` when is that running? It sure isn't running when `onCommand` is executed, as it's *outside* of `onCommand`

Comment: i'm blind LOL how did I not see that, it's 4am and well yea, thank you lMAO.